# Backbone - What is the more efficient scoped finding method for a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm aware there are many ways you can do a DOM query inside a view:

```
$(view.el).find("#element");

$(“#element”, view.el);

view.$("#element");
```

Which one is the best way to go, and why?

Comment: `view.$(...)` is identical to `view.$el.find(...)` (with an extra function call wrapper of course): `$: function(selector) { return this.$el.find(selector); }`. And the difference between `$x.find()` and `$(x, el)` is almost certainly covered elsewhere.

Comment: so merging both Ray's and Karl's answers the best thing to do is `view.$("#element");` ?

Comment: [`view.$`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) would probably be the most idiomatic with Backbone but *best* is highly subjective.

Comment: For optimisation, `view.$("#element");` and `$(view.el).find("#element");` is equivalent (the same thing but one is shorter to write). So you decide what you prefer. The answer you are looking for is : Just dont use the second method.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I think I'll give the accepted answer to @Rayweb_on since he wrote those lines first, but just for the record Karl's answer is good as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bakcbone keeps a reference to the the el of the view, so the last one will be the shorthand version of view.$el.find('#element');

```
view.$("#element"); /// is like I said is just the same that :
view.$el.find('#element');
```

I think this means the last one is the fastest as its only looking into the el and not in the entire DOM and still uses find.

take a look at this link. http://pivotallabs.com/shorthand-for-searching-a-view-s-dom-in-backbone/

Answer (score 2):

Always use find over context selector.

" *It’s true, where possible you should always try to run your selections based on a context however it’s useful just to bare in mind that when you’re passing a context to the jQuery constructor, it creates an extra unnecessary extra function call.
jQuery’s insides run content.find(selector) anyway, so you can technically skip that step if you’re working in a page structure that may not benefit greatly from using context. Below you can see an example of what I’m talking about.* "

Source : [8 jQuery Performance & Optimization Tips You Need In 2010](http://addyosmani.com/blog/8-jquery-performance-tips/) (Tip #6)

Yes the article is old, but it is still true.

TL;DR version : Context selector call the `.find()` function. Using `.find()` directly reduce the number of call.